# Tableview custom cell did select items not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to implement segue when the user taps the cell I have to move to a new view controller

The problem is that the method didselectrow is not being called

I have set the delegate and datasource for the table view too

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@" table vie cell----%lu",(unsigned long)_orderid.count);

    return _orderid.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int section = [indexPath section];
    int row = [indexPath row];

    NSString* CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    if(_orderid != NULL) {

        // set tag to the indexPath.row so we can access it later
        [cell setTag:indexPath.row];    
        NSLog(@"%@ order id tv",_orderid);
        NSLog(@" order id tv %@",_orderid[indexPath.row]);

        cell.orderidlbl.text=_orderid[indexPath.row];
        //cell.orderidlbl.text =_orderid[indexPath.row];

        cell.datelbl.text    =_date[indexPath.row];

        cell.pricelbl.text   =[NSString stringWithFormat:@" ₹ %@",_totprice[indexPath.row]];
        //cell.viewbutton.tag  =indexPath.row;

    }

    //cell.nametxtv.text=[_nametb  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.buynowprice.text=[_buytb objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.regularprice.text=[_regtb objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //cell.lowestoff.text=[_lowesttb objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"i1" sender:self];

}
```

Comment: did you change tablview selection property from storyboard pls confirm , there should be single selection selected

Comment: If you have any tapgesture added ?

Comment: @MikeAlter no I have not changed it is in single selection

Comment: no I have nt yet added any tap gesture and tap gesture too see times doesn't wrk properly

Comment: I dint understand what is the problem I was using collection view in this same page and for that too didselect method didn't wrk so what is the problem?

Comment: @Akshay  Did you checked with breakpoints ?

Comment: How you added Delegate & Datasource  ? , Make sure you are using same class

Comment: @Akshay Check with breakpoint or log statement if the control is actually going there or not. Confirm here once you check.

Comment: print tableView.delegate in cellForRowAtIndexPath and check whether it is set your class ? @Akshay

Comment: @RohanSanap it is not going inside the method

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<MyOrdersViewController 0x7fff35d94010> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableview.'
 now  I am getting this error

Comment: @Akshay Check your storyboard and in this viewcontroller where you have the tableview. See if you have created multiple outlets of tableview. Also check if you have a segue from your viewcontroller to other with the name as i1

Comment: @kapsym yes had an outlet issue now solved that and yes I have an segue with i1

Comment: So what issue is left now. Did you do Single selection in storyboard.You should do that. And also how have you set the tableview delegate. Code or storyboard? It should be either one of them and not both

Comment: have set the delegate storyboard and yes single selection I am not able to perform segue when tapped on the cell

Comment: Ok did you try potting breakpoint in your didselect method to check if its registering your selection?

Comment: And by any chance are you implementing willSelectRowAtIndexpath anywhere?

Comment: yes I have used in one collection view and I tried break point the method is not being called

Comment: and I am getting this weird one "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.
 Stack:(" at log and my app is till running thou

Comment: Can you add the code of your willSelect. Is it for this tableview itself?

Comment: it is the same as did select in the above question still it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a segue with identifier @"i1"

Console log to check if method is actually being called or not

Remove the delegate and set it again programatically